# How to create a user folder when calling win32 API CreateProcessWithLogonW

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, winapi, ctypes

**Context**

I have a Windows desktop program which can be used by different types of user roles.
Each user role has its own set of restricted views and actions, which depend on the outcome of other user actions.
The program communicates to an API and authentication is done with Windows authentication.
In order to test the program end to end, both manually and within a pipeline step, multiple instances of the same program need to run at the same time under different users.

Containers are not an option for the time being.
I am resorting to writing a Python script which uses ctypes.windll.advapi32.CreateProcessWithLogonW to run the program as a specified user.

**Issue**

When calling CreateProcessWithLogonW with dwLogonFlags equal to LOGON_WITH_PROFILE a folder C:\Users\TEMP is created.
All the files created during the program session are stored under that folder.
The folder is destroyed when the program terminates.

When calling CreateProcessWithLogonW with dwLogonFlags equal to LOGON_NETCREDENTIALS_ONLY the folder is not created.
All the files created during the program session are stored under C:\Users<username of logged in user calling CreateProcessWithLogonW>
Authentication is done only after the program has started and the first API call is made, in line with the documentation for this flag.

Neither option is ideal because different users need to store their own data during their sessions.

**Question**

How can I make sure a folder C:\Users<username> is created for each user ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I make sure a folder C:\Users is created for each
> user ?

You can use the [CreateDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createdirectorya) function and specify the [SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/aa379560(v=vs.85)) structure to create a folder.

> lpSecurityDescriptor: A pointer to a SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR structure
> that controls access to the object. If the value of this member is
> NULL, the object is assigned the default security descriptor
> associated with the access token of the calling process. This is not
> the same as granting access to everyone by assigning a NULL
> discretionary access control list (DACL). By default, the default DACL
> in the access token of a process allows access only to the user
> represented by the access token.

You can assign permissions to different users, such as restricting access or writing.

C++ Sample:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <aclapi.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <mq.h.>

#pragma comment(lib, "advapi32.lib")

HRESULT GetSid(
    LPCWSTR wszAccName,
    PSID* ppSid
)
{

    // Validate the input parameters.  
    if (wszAccName == NULL || ppSid == NULL)
    {
        return MQ_ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER;
    }

    // Create buffers that may be large enough.  
    // If a buffer is too small, the count parameter will be set to the size needed.  
    const DWORD INITIAL_SIZE = 32;
    DWORD cbSid = 0;
    DWORD dwSidBufferSize = INITIAL_SIZE;
    DWORD cchDomainName = 0;
    DWORD dwDomainBufferSize = INITIAL_SIZE;
    WCHAR* wszDomainName = NULL;
    SID_NAME_USE eSidType;
    DWORD dwErrorCode = 0;
    HRESULT hr = MQ_OK;

    // Create buffers for the SID and the domain name.  
    *ppSid = (PSID) new BYTE[dwSidBufferSize];
    if (*ppSid == NULL)
    {
        return MQ_ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;
    }
    memset(*ppSid, 0, dwSidBufferSize);
    wszDomainName = new WCHAR[dwDomainBufferSize];
    if (wszDomainName == NULL)
    {
        return MQ_ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;
    }
    memset(wszDomainName, 0, dwDomainBufferSize * sizeof(WCHAR));

    // Obtain the SID for the account name passed.  
    for (; ; )
    {

        // Set the count variables to the buffer sizes and retrieve the SID.  
        cbSid = dwSidBufferSize;
        cchDomainName = dwDomainBufferSize;
        if (LookupAccountNameW(
            NULL,            // Computer name. NULL for the local computer  
            wszAccName,
            *ppSid,          // Pointer to the SID buffer. Use NULL to get the size needed,  
            &cbSid,          // Size of the SID buffer needed.  
            wszDomainName,   // wszDomainName,  
            &cchDomainName,
            &eSidType
        ))
        {
            if (IsValidSid(*ppSid) == FALSE)
            {
                wprintf(L"The SID for %s is invalid.\n", wszAccName);
                dwErrorCode = MQ_ERROR;
            }
            break;
        }
        dwErrorCode = GetLastError();

        // Check if one of the buffers was too small.  
        if (dwErrorCode == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
        {
            if (cbSid > dwSidBufferSize)
            {

                // Reallocate memory for the SID buffer.  
                wprintf(L"The SID buffer was too small. It will be reallocated.\n");
                FreeSid(*ppSid);
                *ppSid = (PSID) new BYTE[cbSid];
                if (*ppSid == NULL)
                {
                    return MQ_ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;
                }
                memset(*ppSid, 0, cbSid);
                dwSidBufferSize = cbSid;
            }
            if (cchDomainName > dwDomainBufferSize)
            {

                // Reallocate memory for the domain name buffer.  
                wprintf(L"The domain name buffer was too small. It will be reallocated.\n");
                delete[] wszDomainName;
                wszDomainName = new WCHAR[cchDomainName];
                if (wszDomainName == NULL)
                {
                    return MQ_ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;
                }
                memset(wszDomainName, 0, cchDomainName * sizeof(WCHAR));
                dwDomainBufferSize = cchDomainName;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            wprintf(L"LookupAccountNameW failed. GetLastError returned: %d\n", dwErrorCode);
            hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(dwErrorCode);
            break;
        }
    }

    delete[] wszDomainName;
    return hr;
}

void main()
{
    PSID sid;
    GetSid(L"strive", &sid);
    DWORD dwRes, dwDisposition;
    PACL pACL = NULL;
    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSD = NULL;
    EXPLICIT_ACCESS ea;
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
    BOOL l = 0;
    // Initialize an EXPLICIT_ACCESS structure for an ACE.
    // The ACE will allow Everyone read access to the key.
    ZeroMemory(&ea, sizeof(EXPLICIT_ACCESS));
    ea.grfAccessPermissions = GENERIC_ALL;
    ea.grfAccessMode = SET_ACCESS;
    ea.grfInheritance = NO_INHERITANCE;
    ea.Trustee.TrusteeForm = TRUSTEE_IS_SID;
    ea.Trustee.TrusteeType = TRUSTEE_IS_USER;
    ea.Trustee.ptstrName = (LPTSTR)sid;

    // Create a new ACL that contains the new ACEs.
    dwRes = SetEntriesInAcl(1, &ea, NULL, &pACL);
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS != dwRes)
    {
        _tprintf(_T("SetEntriesInAcl Error %u\n"), GetLastError());
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    // Initialize a security descriptor.  
    pSD = (PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR)LocalAlloc(LPTR,
        SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_MIN_LENGTH);
    if (NULL == pSD)
    {
        _tprintf(_T("LocalAlloc Error %u\n"), GetLastError());
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    if (!InitializeSecurityDescriptor(pSD,
        SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION))
    {
        _tprintf(_T("InitializeSecurityDescriptor Error %u\n"),
            GetLastError());
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    // Add the ACL to the security descriptor. 
    if (!SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(pSD,
        TRUE,     // bDaclPresent flag   
        pACL,
        FALSE))   // not a default DACL 
    {
        _tprintf(_T("SetSecurityDescriptorDacl Error %u\n"),
            GetLastError());
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    // Initialize a security attributes structure.
    sa.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = pSD;
    sa.bInheritHandle = FALSE;

    // Use the security attributes to set the security descriptor 
    // when you create a key.
    l = CreateDirectory(L"C:\\Users\\strive", &sa);
 
Cleanup:
    if (pACL)
        LocalFree(pACL);
    if (pSD)
        LocalFree(pSD);
    return;
}
```